# WordPress: Add custom add_filter for custom functions

Tags: php, wordpress, email, filter

I am coping with the scenario where I need to filter content of my custom function. My function is used for sending emails but I need to filter it just like wp_mail hook do.

Here is my function:

```
function koku_crm_send_sendgrid($sendgrid_api_key, $to, $subject, $text, $html) {

    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($sendgrid_api_key);
    $mail = new KCSendGrid\Mail();
    $from = new KCSendGrid\Email(get_bloginfo( 'name' ), get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ));
    $mail->setFrom($from);
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

    $content = new KCSendGrid\Content("text/plain", $text);
    $mail->addContent($content);

    $content = new KCSendGrid\Content("text/html", $html);
    $mail->addContent($content);

    $personalization = new KCSendGrid\Personalization();
    $to = new KCSendGrid\Email(null, $to);
    $personalization->addTo($to);
    $mail->addPersonalization($personalization);

    $sendgrid->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

}
```

I want to filter that "$to" variable before sending the email. Something similar to the [wp_mail filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail).

I have search a lot, please help me in this regards. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: So you want to create your own filter/hook, that other modules then can hook into to change who the mail is send to? If so, research how custom hooks are implemented ... https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+create+own+filters

Comment: You mean apply_filters(); function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

Comment: Hi @Mo'menMohamed , I want to create something like [wp_mail filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail)

Comment: I just want to filter that **$to** parameter from with in my plugin before that above function run, that what wp_mail hook do.

Comment: apply_filters($tag, $value) passes the 'value' argument to each of the functions 'hooked' (using  add_filter) into the specified filter 'tag'. Each function performs some processing on the value and returns a modified value to be passed to the next function in the sequence.

For example, by default (in Wordpress 2.9) the the_content filter passes the value through the following sequence of functions:

wptexturize
convert_smilies
convert_chars
wpautop
shortcode_unautop
prepend_attachment
do_shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `apply_filters($tag, $value)` passes the 'value' argument to each of the functions 'hooked' (using  add_filter) into the specified filter 'tag'. Each function performs some processing on the value and returns a modified value to be passed to the next function in the sequence.

Now let’s look at an easy example in the Customizr theme. Let’s change the url of the link in the logo:

```
// Change url that is linked from logo
add_filter( 'tc_logo_link_url', 'change_site_main_link' );
function change_site_main_link() {
  return 'http://example.com';
}
```

Inside the Customizr core code, in the function that displays the logo (in class-header-header_main.php), Customizr has:

```
apply_filters( ‘tc_logo_link_url’, esc_url( home_url( ‘/’ ) ) )
```

This is where our add_filter() is hooking itself. The esc_url() function eliminates invalid characters etc. in urls and the home_url() function retrieves the home url for the site. So without any filtering, the ‘tc_logo_link_url’ filter returns the home page’s address.

In this example, we didn’t even take any notice of the incoming arguments (the home url), because we knew we were just going to completely overwrite it.

Remember: When you use a filter, you must always return something.